# jQuery parent in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

Why I can't delete tr. What is wrong in this source code :

1. JS code

   ```
   $(".delete").click(function() {
       var parent_1 = $(this).parent();
       var parent_2 = $(parent_1).parent();
       $(parent_2).remove(); 
   });
   ```
2. HTML code

   ```
    <html> <table>
      <tr id="row_1">  
           <td>    <input type="submit" class="delete" value="1" /> </td>
      </tr>
    </table> </html>
   ```

Comment: <table>
 <tr id="row_1"> 
 <td> <input type="submit" class="delete" value="1" /> </td>
 </tr>
    </table>

Comment: I can't add HTML code

Comment: [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/nTLzz/) . whats the problem??

Comment: I think it should work. You can make the code better: `$(this).parents().eq(1).remove();`

Comment: Are you running this code *after* the DOM is finished building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work but you can make the code better. Standard way of declaring jQuery object is `$(selector)`. Your `parent_1` and `parent_2` are both an `object` so no need to put it inside `$()`. Instead you can do it like this `$parent_1` and `$parent_2`, so it is easy to recognize that both are jQuery objects.

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    var $parent_1 = $(this).parent(),
        $parent_2 = $parent_1.parent();

    $parent_2.remove(); 
});
```

You can still improve it further with the use of `parents()` selector together with `eq()` to specify which ancestor you tying to get.

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    $(this).parents().eq(1).remove();// the grandfather of $(".delete") which is <tr>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use a little brushing up but it should remove the row. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/MeUnt/) with one of the cleaner ways to do that: also on a side note, once you call something with jQuery and store it in a variable you already have access to all of jQuery's functions. (its already a jQuery object and does not need to be re-passed to jQuery. Example:

You have:

```
var parent_1 = $(this).parent();
var parent_2 = $(parent_1).parent();
```

You could do:

```
var parent_1 = $(this).parent();
var parent_2 = parent_1.parent();
```